# Elisp function return value

Tags: function, emacs, return, elisp

I'm having a (probably) dumb problem with Elisp. I want a function to return `t` or `nil` depending on a `when` condition. This is the code:

```
(defun tmr-active-timer-p
  "Returns t or nil depending of if there's an active timer"
  (progn
    (if (not (file-exists-p tmr-file))
        nil
      ; (... more code)
      )
    )
)
```

But I'm having an error. I'm not sure how to make a function return a value... I've read a function return the last expression result value but in this case, I wan't to make something like (PHP mess warning):

```
// code

if ($condition) {
  return false;
}

// more code...
```

Maybe I'm missing the point and functional programming doesn't allow this approach?

Comment: Ok the problem was actually the lack of parenthesis before tmr-active-timer-p.

Comment: You need to accept the answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**First**, you need an argument list after `tmr-active-timer-p`; the [`defun`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/defun.html) syntax is

```
(defun function-name (arg1 arg2 ...) code...)
```

**Second**, you do not need to wrap the body in [`progn`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/progn.html).

**Third**, the return value is the last form evaluated. If your case you can just write

```
(defun tmr-active-timer-p ()
  "Returns t or nil depending of if there's an active timer."
  (when (file-exists-p tmr-file)
      ; (... more code)
    ))
```

then it will return `nil` if the file does not exist (because `(when foo bar)` is the same as `(if foo (progn bar) nil)`).

**Finally**, hanging parentheses are considered to be a poor code formatting style in lisp.

PS. Emacs Lisp does not have [`return`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_return.htm), but it does have [Nonlocal Exits](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Nonlocal-Exits.html). I urge you to avoid them unless you *really* know what you are doing.

Comment: Well, your answer was correct. Basically there is no return sintaxis. You cannot return easily from a middle of a function in Elisp and probably is wouldn't be a good idea because of the functional paradigm.

Thanks for the advice with hanging parenthesis.